# How to define a range over multiple sheets with COUNTIF?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count the correct amount of answers across multiple sheets in a workbook. For this I tried using the following line (as instructed by other topics here on SO):

```
=COUNTIF((Sheet1!B6, Sheet2!B6, Sheet3!B6), "Yes")
```

So I wish to count the amounts of "Yes" in the B6 cell across all sheets.  But this only throws a "Formula parse error". I have also tried the following (also following a suggestion here on SO):

```
=COUNTIF((Sheet1:Sheet2:Sheet3!B6), "Yes")
```

But this does also throw the same error and this time the Sheet names are not even highlighted like they are in my former example.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and could help me solve this problem?

Comment: can you link those suggestions you found here on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when constructing the array you need to use `{}` parenthesis:

```
=COUNTIF({Sheet1!B6, Sheet2!B6, Sheet3!B6}, "Yes")
```